# SQL Server - Windowed Functions

Tags: sql-server, window-functions

So, I'm in need of some help with some homework.

Below is the schema of the parts of the database that I need to use. 
[image: Table Scema]

I'm sure that there are some redundancies in it (I would appreciate any help with the setup as well). Anyways, here is the assignment:

> - The sales manager would now like you to create a report that ranks her products by both their total sales and total sales quantity (each 
>     will be its own column).   Create a stored procedure that returns
>     the following columns but also with the two new rank columns added.
>
>   Product Name |  Orders Count | Total Sales Value | Total Sales    Quantity
> - The CEO would like to know the sales based on last month's sales.     Please provide her with a query to rank the products by the number of 
>     orders in the last month.  There should be NO SKIPPED NUMBERS.
> - Create a SELECT statement that generates a list of orders with    customer id, order date, etc.     ***Use the row number function to
>     generate a unique id for each row that is sorted by order date DESC

Comment: I would say a Cart contains Orders.  An Order contains OrderItems.  An OrderItem has a ProductId.  So one cart to many orders.  One order to many orderitems.  One orderitem to one product.  I dont see any value linking cart to orderitems or products.

Comment: This is your homework, and you want other people to do it for you?  What have you done so far?

Comment: Did you professor provide this database or did you create it? I ask because there are a lot of issues with that database.

Comment: Sean, I created it. I was pretty sure that something was wrong with it. What issues do you see? What can I do to make it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it

```
CREATE PROCEDURE report_salesmanager 
AS 
  WITH cte_main AS 
  ( 
             SELECT     p.NAME, 
                        Isnull(Count(DISTINCT o.orderid), 0)  corderid, 
                        Sum(Isnull(o.ordertotal, 0))          sordertotal, 
                        Sum (Isnull(oi.orderitemquantity, 0)) sorderitemquantity 
             FROM       product p 
             LEFT JOIN  orderitem oi 
             INNER JOIN orders o 
             ON         o.orderid - oi.orderid 
             ON         p.productid = oi.productid 
             GROUP BY   p.NAME), cte_rank_value AS 
  ( 
           SELECT   NAME, 
                    Rank() OVER( ORDER BY sordertotal DESC) rk 
           FROM     cte_main), cte_rank_qtd AS 
  ( 
           SELECT   NAME, 
                    Rank() OVER( ORDER BY sorderitemquantity DESC) rk 
           FROM     cte_main) 
  SELECT     a.NAME [Product Name], 
             a.corderid, 
             [Orders Count] a.sordertotal [Total Sales Value], 
             b.rk [Rank Total Sales Value], 
             a.sorderitemquantity [Total Sales Quantity], 
             c.rk [Rank Total Sales Quantity] 
  FROM       cte_main a 
  INNER JOIN cte_rank_value b 
  ON         a.NAME = b.NAME 
  INNER JOIN cte_rank_qtd c 
  ON         a.NAME = c.NAME

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE report_ceo 
AS 
  DECLARE @somedateLastMonth DATE = Dateadd(-1,m,Getdate()) WITH cte_main AS 
  ( 
             SELECT     p.NAME, 
                        Isnull(Count(DISTINCT o.orderid), 0)  corderid, 
                        Sum(Isnull(o.ordertotal, 0))          sordertotal, 
                        Sum (Isnull(oi.orderitemquantity, 0)) sorderitemquantity 
             FROM       product p 
             INNER JOIN orderitem oi 
             INNER JOIN orders o 
             ON         o.orderid - oi.orderid 
             ON         p.productid = oi.productid 
             WHERE      Year(o.orderdate) * 100 + Month(o.orderdate) = Year(@somedateLastMonth) * 100 + Month(@somedateLastMonth)
             GROUP BY   p.NAME), 
    cte_rank_value AS 
  ( 
           SELECT   NAME, 
                    Rank() OVER( ORDER BY sordertotal DESC) rk 
           FROM     cte_main), 
    cte_rank_qtd AS 
  ( 
           SELECT   NAME, 
                    Rank() OVER( ORDER BY sorderitemquantity DESC) rk 
           FROM     cte_main) 
  SELECT     a.NAME [Product Name], 
             a.corderid, 
             [Orders Count] a.sordertotal [Total Sales Value], 
             b.rk [Rank Total Sales Value], 
             a.sorderitemquantity [Total Sales Quantity], 
             c.rk [Rank Total Sales Quantity] 
  FROM       cte_main a 
  INNER JOIN cte_rank_value b 
  ON         a.NAME = b.NAME 
  INNER JOIN cte_rank_qtd c 
  ON         a.NAME = c.NAME
go


SELECT     Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY o.orderdate DESC, o.ordertime DESC) rowNumber ,
           * 
FROM       product p 
INNER JOIN orderitem oi 
INNER JOIN orders o 
ON         o.orderid - oi.orderid 
ON         p.productid = oi.productid 
INNER JOIN cart c 
ON         c.orderid = o.orderid
```